# sql server - query. Returning time between failures

Tags: sql-server

I have details on what builds passed and what builds failed. I want to be able to measure the time in between failures (meaning there is at least 1 pass in between 2 failures). I have example data and example queries I have so far linked [here](http://rextester.com/IPB58958).

What I want my query to output given this data is just 2 rows

```
FailedDt             |        SecondFailedDt
-------------------------------------------------

1/2/2010 12:00:00 AM |        1/4/2010 12:00:00 AM

1/6/2010 12:00:00 AM |        1/10/2010 12:00:00 AM
```

How can I modify my query to get the output I want?

Comment: A good question, thx for the linked example! There you are using several tables to store intermediate data. Is this a given structure or something one might let aside? And plase state the version of your SQL-Server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be much easier than your approach:

Just paste this into an empty query window and execute... Adapt to your needs

```
declare @rsBuildDetails table(dt datetime, build varchar(255), val varchar(255));

insert into @rsBuildDetails (dt, build, val) values 
 ('20100101', '1', 'pass')
,('20100102', '2', 'fail')
,('20100103', '3', 'pass')
,('20100104', '4', 'fail')
,('20100105', '5', 'fail')
,('20100106', '6', 'fail')
,('20100107', '7', 'pass')
,('20100108', '8', 'pass')
,('20100109', '9', 'pass')
,('20100110', '10', 'fail');

with passed as
(
    select * 
    from @rsBuildDetails
    where val='pass'
)
select distinct preFail.dt AS FailedDt
               ,postFail.dt AS SecondFailedDt
from passed
outer apply(
    select top 1 pre.*
    from @rsBuildDetails as pre
    where pre.dt<passed.dt 
      and pre.val='fail'
    order by pre.dt desc
) as preFail
outer apply(
    select top 1 post.*
    from @rsBuildDetails as post
    where post.dt>passed.dt 
      and post.val='fail'
    order by post.dt asc
) as postFail
where preFail.dt IS NOT NULL and postFail.dt IS NOT NULL
```

The result

```
FailedDt                SecondFailedDt
2010-01-02 00:00:00.000 2010-01-04 00:00:00.000
2010-01-06 00:00:00.000 2010-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Looks like cross apply works better than outer apply. However, I am actually using a custom DB platform that works similar to SQL but not exactly SQL. So it doesn't have cross apply or outer apply. I also don't fully understand what the cross apply does. Is there a way to rewrite this without using applies?

Comment: @jyim89  As your question is tagged with "SQL-Server" only, it would be very kind of you to vote up and accept this question here as solved and ask a new follow-up question, how to transfer this to "pure" ANSI SQL. If you post a link to your new question here, I'll prepare an answer soon. (reputation points addicted :-) )

Comment: @shungo, sorry still not very familiar with stackoverflow :). Here is the new link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493289/changing-sql-server-query-to-pur-ansi-sql-query