# Changing SQL Server query to pure ANSI SQL query

Tags: ansi-sql

I am working on a database system that uses SQL syntax. However I am unable to use the cross apply in the code below. Is there a way to rewrite this without applies?

```
 declare @rsBuildDetails table(dt datetime, build varchar(255), val varchar(255));

insert into @rsBuildDetails (dt, build, val) 
values ('20100101', '1', 'pass')
      ,('20100102', '2', 'fail')
      ,('20100103', '3', 'pass')
      ,('20100104', '4', 'fail')
      ,('20100105', '5', 'fail')
      ,('20100106', '6', 'fail')
      ,('20100107', '7', 'pass')
      ,('20100108', '8', 'pass')
      ,('20100109', '9', 'pass')
      ,('20100110', '10', 'fail');

with passed as
(
    select * 
    from @rsBuildDetails
    where val='pass'
)
select distinct 
    preFail.dt AS FailedDt,
    postFail.dt AS SecondFailedDt
from 
    passed
cross apply
    (select top 1 
         pre.*
     from 
         @rsBuildDetails as pre
     where 
         pre.dt < passed.dt 
         and pre.val = 'fail'
     order by 
         pre.dt desc) as preFail
cross apply
    (select top 1 
         post.*
     from 
         @rsBuildDetails as post
     where 
         post.dt > passed.dt 
         and post.val = 'fail'
     order by 
         post.dt asc) as postFail
```

Comment: Do you really want a pure ANSI SQL query, or do you want a specific RDBMS?

Comment: @Tim, Shnugo was able to answer my question below. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to transfer the CTE and all applies to inlined sub-selects:

```
declare @rsBuildDetails table(dt datetime, build varchar(255), val varchar(255));

insert into @rsBuildDetails (dt, build, val) values 
 ('20100101', '1', 'pass')
,('20100102', '2', 'fail')
,('20100103', '3', 'pass')
,('20100104', '4', 'fail')
,('20100105', '5', 'fail')
,('20100106', '6', 'fail')
,('20100107', '7', 'pass')
,('20100108', '8', 'pass')
,('20100109', '9', 'pass')
,('20100110', '10', 'fail');

select *
from
(
    select distinct
           (
            select top 1 pre.Dt
            from @rsBuildDetails as pre
            where pre.dt<passed.dt 
              and pre.val='fail'
            order by pre.dt desc
           ) as FailedDt
         ,(
            select top 1 post.Dt
            from @rsBuildDetails as post
            where post.dt>passed.dt 
              and post.val='fail'
            order by post.dt asc
          ) AS SecondFailedDt
    from 
    (
        select * 
        from @rsBuildDetails
        where val='pass'
    ) AS passed
) AS tbl
where tbl.FailedDt IS NOT NULL 
  AND tbl.SecondFailedDt IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. I will accept the answer as soon as it lets me.